# Best prediction model/ method for predicting baby names by year

Tags: r, time-series, linear-regression, prediction

Stack overflow people good evening - I have a question related to predicting names. So I am using an R package called babynames. The package has the following variables `(Year(1880 to 2017), Sex(M/F), Name, n(this is count of name in that year), Prop (proportionality of that name))` - 
example

```
year sex   name          n   prop
   <dbl> <chr> <chr>     <int>  <dbl>
 1  1880 F     Mary       7065 0.0724
 2  1880 F     Anna       2604 0.0267
 3  1880 F     Emma       2003 0.0205
 4  1880 F     Elizabeth  1939 0.0199
 5  1880 F     Minnie     1746 0.0179
```

now my goal is to predict the most popular names for 2025, 2030, and 2035. My question is what would be the best method if any to predict popular names in future? I thought of using a time series model but these names don't have any seasonality so the results would be pretty inaccurate - for example look at the name Mary and how the use of the name changed over the years 
[image: Use of Name Mary by year]

so it seems that we dont really have a predictive pattern, and there might be more missing predictive variables like race, religion, last name, area that might be helpful to make a prediction - to me it seems that random guessing might be better than trying to fit any type of predictive model. What model would you recommend if any?

thank you

Comment: This would be on-topic at [DataScience.SE](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/). Depends do you want to explicitly model the effect of celebrity baby names? And do you only want to do it US-wide, in aggregate, not consider the (strong) regional dependencies?

Comment: @smci While I agree with you in that there a many different ways in filtering/looking/summarising data, the bottom line is that forecasting will be difficult on all levels and in all but a few isolated cases. A more interesting (and promising) way to analyse this kind of data is to explore whether certain external events have had a (causal) effect on the popularity of certain names, and if so how strong an effect. Anyway, I agree it's an interesting question in the wider context.

Comment: @MauritsEvers: there's also a difference in cause between a name simply becoming unfashionable (e.g. not currently trendy or represented among famous people e.g. ['Heather'](https://qz.com/1390135/the-epic-rise-and-fall-of-the-name-heather/)), vs. being part of a declining demographic e.g. the US name 'Norman' since the 1960s in part due to a decline in the WASP demographic.

Comment: @smci I completely agree; which is why forecasting using a "best prediction model/method" simply doesn't work.

Comment: thank you @smci and Maurits Evers. Yes, exhausting and thinking about this in different ways I came to the conclusion that we just dont have enough strong predictor variables. If we had things like religion, race, last names, and popular events / popular people then my idea was to see if the names are correlated in any way to those variables, but seems that lack of data prevents us from forming anything conclusive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's difficult/impossible to predict (baby) names as the popularity of names are often driven/affected by historical, sociological and other external (and un-accountable) events.

---

Take the pattern in the popularity of the name "Mary" as an example.

- It is conceivable that the increase in the popularity of that name between around 1910 and 1920 is linked to the coronation of Queen [Mary of Teck](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mary_of_Teck) in 1911.
- The second post-1940 increase may be linked to the death of King George V and the subsequent new status of Mary of Teck as "Queen Mother" in 1936.
- Her death in 1953 may have contributed to a general decrease in popularity in the following years.

---

Another (in)famous example is the popularity of the name "Adolf"/"Adolph" with a near-exponential decay after around 1918.

```
library(babynames)
library(tidyverse)
babynames %>%
    filter(name %in% c("Adolph", "Adolf")) %>%
    group_by(year) %>%
    summarise(n = sum(n)) %>%
    ggplot(aes(year, n)) +
    geom_line()
```

[image]

---

### Update: An explorative time series analysis

I was curious to see what we can do with the "Adolph"/"Adolf" data in the context of time series analysis. I've chosen that data rather than the "Mary" data on account of its simpler time series structure. Hopefully, this will give you some ideas for further critical analyses, and for getting a better understanding about what you can and cannot do.

Let's start by turning the data into a `ts` time-series object.

```r
library(babynames)
library(tidyverse)
library(zoo)
ts <- babynames %>%
    filter(name %in% c("Adolph", "Adolf")) %>%
    group_by(year) %>%
    summarise(n = sum(n)) %>%
    full_join(data.frame(year = seq(min(.$year), max(.$year)))) %>%
    arrange(year) %>%
    pull(n) %>%
    ts(start = 1880, frequency = 1) %>%
    na.approx()
```

Since data for years 2012 and 2015 are missing, we need to replace `NA`s with "sensible" values. Here we use `zoo::na.approx` to replace these missing counts with interpolated values.

Since we're working with time series count data it's often useful to log-transform values. Alternatively we can use `forecast::BoxCox` to perform a [Box-Cox transformation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_transform#Box%E2%80%93Cox_transformation) of the data using an optimal value for `lambda` (see `?forecast::BoxCox` for details).

```r
library(forecast)
ts <- BoxCox(ts, lambda = "auto")
attr(ts, "lambda")
#[1] 0.08813758
```

As expected, the optimal `lambda` parameter is close to zero, suggesting an optimal transformation that is very close to a log-transformation.

Let's take a look a the differenced and Box-Cox-transformed data

```r
autoplot(diff(ts))
```

[image]

The data show some more-or-less stationary periods; we also see some spikes that are indicative of non-stationary events, the most obvious ones around the year 1912.

Ignoring these spikes and other time-series abnormalities for now, we can use `forecast::auto.arima` to obtain a rough idea about the underlying ARIMA process.

```r
auto.arima(ts)
#Series: ts
#ARIMA(0,1,3)
#
#Coefficients:
#          ma1     ma2     ma3
#      -0.2568  0.0335  0.2605
#s.e.   0.0824  0.0833  0.0753
#
#sigma^2 estimated as 0.09039:  log likelihood=-28.38
#AIC=64.77   AICc=65.07   BIC=76.45
```

The "best" model corresponds to an AR(3) model with a single degree of differencing.

We now return to the spikes seen around year 1912. An interesting question in the context of time-series intervention analysis may be to ask when did these (intervention) events take place and what was their effect on the popularity of the name. To do so, we can use an ARIMAX model which we build around the ARIMA(0, 1, 3) model inferred from `auto.arima`. We consider a range of different intervention years between 1910 and 1920, and fit separate ARIMAX models for separate intervention years. For every model we then extract the model coefficients along with the models' AIC and log-likelihood values.

```r
library(TSA)
df <- imap(
    setNames(1910:1920, 1910:1920), ~arimax(
        ts,
        order = c(0, 1, 3),
        xtransf = data.frame(I = +(time(ts) == .x)),
        transfer = list(c(1, 0)))) %>%
    map(~ c(.x$coef, AIC = .x$aic, loglik = .x$loglik)) %>%
    map_df(bind_rows, .id = "yr_intervention")
df
## A tibble: 11 x 8
#   yr_intervention    ma1      ma2   ma3 `I-AR1` `I-MA0`   AIC loglik
#   <chr>            <dbl>    <dbl> <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl>
# 1 1910            -0.264  0.0157  0.252  0.991   0.270   66.0  -28.0
# 2 1911            -0.260  0.0314  0.258 -0.274  -0.305   64.5  -27.2
# 3 1912            -0.377 -0.0292  0.204  0.981   1.27    49.0  -19.5
# 4 1913            -0.259  0.0411  0.256 -0.664   0.132   65.9  -27.9
# 5 1914            -0.305 -0.0118  0.255  0.967   0.443   65.0  -27.5
# 6 1915            -0.276  0.00539 0.222  0.934   0.599   62.5  -26.3
# 7 1916            -0.264  0.0368  0.256  0.644   0.183   66.3  -28.1
# 8 1917            -0.257  0.0356  0.260  0.184   0.215   65.9  -28.0
# 9 1918            -0.257  0.0361  0.258 -0.357   0.0611  66.7  -28.3
#10 1919            -0.265  0.0425  0.262  0.613  -0.293   65.4  -27.7
#11 1920            -0.260  0.0361  0.264  0.0705 -0.160   66.3  -28.1
```

We see that an ARIMA(0, 1, 3) model with an intervention in year 1912 gives the best fit to the data (resulting in the smallest AIC and largest log-likelihood).

We have now found a model that consists of (1) an ARIMA-type process and (2) a single intervention event. Pending a further and more in-depth critical evaluation of the model, you could now use the model to forecast into the future. Whether this is useful/sensible or not is questionable, so I will leave it at that.

To come back to your original question about what is the "[b]est prediction model/ method for predicting baby names by year" the answer would always be: it depends. There is no single "best (prediction) model".

Comment: thank you so much Dr. Maurits for detailed explanation. I am going over your prediction model, and understanding the motivation behind it. I will also post an update with my findings and the way I was going about it.